# Update rows in a table with results from query

Tags: sql, mariadb

server: 10.3.32-MariaDB

I've got a table with the columns ts (timestamp), some values and a column which is empty. There is a query which outputs ts and the value I want to insert into that empty column. Goal is to update the table for where there is a corresponding entry (ts matches ts) in the query.

How do I do this for the entire table?

Two attempts that don't work:

1/

```
UPDATE avg1h
SET pwr_peak = peaks. Peak
FROM (
    SELECT ts, MAX(pwr) AS peak
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ts
            - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) SECOND
            - INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) MINUTE AS ts,
            CASE WHEN pwr < 0 THEN 0 ELSE pwr END as pwr
        FROM avg15m
    ) AS peak15m
    GROUP BY ts
) AS peaks
WHERE avg1h.ts = peaks.ts
```

2/

```
UPDATE avg1h
SET avg1h.pwr_peak = peaks. Peak
FROM avg1h
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ts, MAX(pwr) AS peak
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ts
            - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) SECOND
            - INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) MINUTE AS ts,
            CASE WHEN pwr < 0 THEN 0 ELSE pwr END as pwr
        FROM avg15m
    ) AS peak15m
    GROUP BY ts
) AS peaks
ON avg1h.ts = peaks.ts
```

The query (AS peaks) outputs the 'ts' and 'peak' columns correctly.

Comment: Code looks more like sql-server than mysql/mariadb - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html for mysql syntax paying particular attention to Multiple-table syntax: NB:- you cannot just drop code from sql dialect to another. Need more help  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is the answer:
Maybe I got mixed up in SQL dialects...

```
UPDATE avg1h, (
    SELECT ts, MAX(pwr) AS peak
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ts
            - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) SECOND
            - INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) MINUTE AS ts,
            CASE WHEN pwr < 0 THEN 0 ELSE pwr END as pwr
        FROM avg15m
    ) AS peak15m
    GROUP BY ts
) AS peaks
SET avg1h.pwr_peak = peaks.peak
WHERE avg1h.ts = peaks.ts AND avg1h.pwr_peak IS NULL
```